# Ajax- Spring MVC

Tags: java, ajax, spring

Я хотела сделать поиск пользователей без перезагрузки страницы, выбрала для этого  Ajax. Помогите понять причину ошибки. jsp-страница со скриптом:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function search() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType : "application/json",
                url : "/search",
                <%--url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/search/",
                data: "name="+$("#id").val(),/

                success: function (res) {
                    var result = "<thead> <tr><th>Имя</th> <th>Фамилия</th><th>Отчество</th> </thead>";
                    result+="<tbody>";
                    $.each(res,function (k,v) {
                        result+="<tr>";
                        result+="<td>";
                        result+=v.id;
                        result+="</td>";
                        result+="<td>";
                        result+=v.name;
                        result+="</td>";
                        result+="</tr>";
                    })
                    $("#result").html(result);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("error ");
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

контроллер:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    private DAO dao;
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView visitHome() {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.setViewName("index.jsp");
      return model;
    }
        @RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody List<? extends User> ajaxSearch (@RequestParam String id) {
        List<? extends User> list = dao.getUser(id);
         return list;
    }
```

В итоге при нажатии на кнопку поиска ошибка :

```
<body><h1>HTTP Status 404 – Не найдено</h1>
<hr class="line"/>
<p><b>Type</b> Status Report</p>
<p><b>Message</b> Not found</p>
<p><b>Description</b> The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing
    to disclose that one exists.</p>
<hr class="line"/>
<h3>Apache Tomcat/9.0.21</h3></body>
```

Comment: А что в консоли браузера пишет? (F12)

Comment: @ValentynHruzytskyi  последнее это как раз ошибка из консоли - 400, 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()
jquery.min.js:4 POST http://localhost:8080/arm_war_exploded/search 400
send @ jquery.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
search @ (index):39
onclick @ (index):20

Comment: Я не совсем уверен, но я вижу, что Вы принимаете параметр `id` в методе `ajaxSearch`, а формируете запрос c параметром `name`, а не `id`. Т.е. тут то-ли добавить параметр `value="name"` в  `@PathVariable`, толи поменять `name` на `id` в построении урлы запроса.
Что б я сделал:
1) старый добрый сисаут: выведите с помощью `Console.log` урлу которую формируете на странице. Посмотрите или она соответствует ожидаемому `/search?id=X`
2) создайте самый простой GET запрос без параметров и приймите его в контроллере самым простым методом, который вернет стрингу. Выведите ету стрингу.

Comment: Я сталкивался с подобным -чаще всего 2 ошибки:
1) запрос не находит контроллера
2) неправильно сериализуется ответ на стрвнице (ошибка обработки  ответа - обьекта, который получен от сервера).

Следует упростить все донельзя и добавлять функционал постепенно.